# Sth wrong with python types/ print to Popen error

Tags: python, subprocess

Ok, I enjoyed with python subprocess.Popen and found one strange thing:

```
OnlineListener = subprocess.Popen(("python", prog_dir + "online.py", prog_dir, port),
                                  shell=True,
                                  stdout=None,
                                  stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

print(b"f", file=OnlineListener.stdin, flush=True)
```

But I got strange err:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/##########/PycharmProjects/#####/main.py", line 53, in <module>
    processes = run_proc()
  File "C:/##########/PycharmProjects/#####/main.py", line 27, in run_proc
    print(b"f", file=OnlineListener.stdin, flush=True)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

> bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

I thought the error is due to `b"f"`, but actually:

```
print(type(b'f')) # return: <class 'bytes'>
```

Can someone help me with this?
**UPD.**
Maybe I no really need answer for this question, but just look at this:

```
    scoper.stdin.write("end\n".encode())
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

##################***BUT***########################.

```
    scoper.stdin.write("end\n")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: What is your code meant to do? Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: You probably want `shell=False` if you are using a tuple as the first argument.

Comment: Regarding your updated question, my answer suggests doing only one of the two solutions, but not both. Initializing `Popen` with `encoding` would make the `stdin` attribute a text stream, making a call to `write` with a `bytes` object raise the `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes` error. If the input to that program is meant to be all text I would suggest that you simply initialize `Popen` with `encoding`, and use `print` for output.

Answer (score 1):

The [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function always treats the given file-like object as a text stream, and calling `print` with `b'f'` would simply output `"b'f'"` as text. But [`Popen.stdin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdin) would be a bytes stream unless an `encoding` argument is given, which you did not, so printing anything to it would result in the said error.

To fix this, you can either use the `encoding` argument when initializing `Popen`:

```
OnlineListener = subprocess.Popen("python",
                                  shell=True,
                                  stdout=None,
                                  stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                  encoding='utf-8')
```

or use the `write` method instead of `print`:

```
OnlineListener.stdin.write(b'f\n')
```